# Android support multi screens issue on real devices

Tags: android, layout

I am creating an app in Android that should support multiple screens and I've implemented techniques to support multi screens as follow:
- Created layouts folder for **small, normal, large and xlarge**
- Provided images for **drawable-hdpi, drawable-ldpi, drawable-mdpi and drawable-xhdpi**
- Added code below to app manifest:

```
<supports-screens
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true"
    android:anyDensity="true"  />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

and have adjusted layout editor inputs as shown to the image below

[image: layout issue]

The problem is that these layouts are not working fine on real devices and there are
elements are larger or smaller and its margins are sometimes bigger or smaller than the layout editor preview

layout example

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_refresh"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
        android:background="@color/transparent"
        android:onClick="refreshBtnAction" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="280dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="85dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="19dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:divider="#E9CE9A"
        android:fadingEdge="none"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Please if you can explain what I should do to ensure that layouts are working fine across real devices, I would be grateful
Thanks in advance

Comment: If you don't have access to all the devices you like to test on, Google offers a service where people will test your app in Beta, and let you know how it goes.

Comment: thank you so much @durbnpoisn, I will use it for the upcoming tests

Answer (score 0):

I find it best to use sp instead of dp and also use the predefined widths & heights whenever you can. I mean things like android:layoutWidth="match_parent" and work with LayoutWeigt. Following is an example that makes the 2 buttons always 80% and 20%, no matter what the screen resolution is (see the attributes weightSum and layout_weight):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="100"
    >


    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/bResults"
        android:text="Try Command"
        android:layout_weight="20" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tbPassword"
        android:layout_weight="80"
        android:checked="true"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

This way you dont need any "layout folders", only the folders for the different image-resolutions are needed. Im not sure with what Editor you work but with Android Studio or Eclipse these folders will get automatically build usually. And write "sp" where you have "dp", that also helps. I never had an issue with this when using the given advice. My Apps look same on a 3.7 Inch like on a Nexus 10.

Comment: Thanks so much @Senchay, it didn't work for me, still have the same issue